# Run DAG at specific time each day

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I've read multiple examples about `schedule_interval`, `start_date` and the Airflow docs multiple times aswell, and I still can't wrap my head around:

How do I get to execute my DAG at a specific time each day? E.g say it's now 9:30 (AM), I deploy my DAG and I want it to get executed at 10:30

I have tried

```py
with DAG(
    "test",
    default_args=default_args,
    description= "test",
    schedule_interval = "0 10 * * *",
    start_date = days_ago(0),
    tags = ["goodie"]) as dag:
```

but for some reason that wasnt run today. I have tried different `start_dates` altso `start_date = datetime.datetime(2021,6,23)` but it does not get executed.

If I replace `days_ago(0)` with `days_ago(1)` it is behind 1 day all the time i.e it does not get run today but did run yesterday

Isn't there an easy way to say "I deploy my DAG now, and I want to get it executed with this cron-syntax" (which I assume is what most people want) instead of calculating an execution time, based on `start_date`, `schedule_interval` and figuring out, how to interpret it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I replace days_ago(0) with days_ago(1) it is behind 1 day all the time

It's not behind. You are simply confusing Airflow scheduling mechanizem with cron jobs. In cron jobs you just provide a cron expression and it schedule accordingly - This is not how it works in Airflow.

In Airflow the scheduling is calculated by `start_date` + `schedule interval`. Airflow execute the job at the END of the interval. This is consistent with how data pipelines usually works. Today you are processing yesterday data so at the end of this day you want to start a process that will go over yesterday records.

As a rule - NEVER use dynamic start date.

Setting:

```
with DAG(
    "test",
    default_args=default_args,
    description= "test",
    schedule_interval = "0 10 * * *",
    start_date = datetime(2021,06,23, 10 ,0), # 2021-06-23 10:00
    tags = ["goodie"]) as dag:
```

Means that the first will start on `2021-06-24 10:00` this run `execution_date` will be `2021-06-23 10:00`. The second run will start on `2021-06-25 10:00` this run `execution_date` will be `2021-06-24 10:00`

Since this is a source of confusion to many new users there is an architecture change in progress [AIP-39 Richer scheduler_interval](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-39+Richer+scheduler_interval) which will decople between WHEN to run and WHAT interval to consider with this run. It will be available in Airflow 2.3.0

**UPDATE** for `Airflow>=2.3.0`:
AIP-39 Richer scheduler_interval has been completed and released
It added [Timetable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/timetable.html#timetables) support so you can [Customizing DAG Scheduling with Timetables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/timetable.html)

Comment: Just to clarify - what does it mean, that `execution_date` is `2021-06-23` ? Does it mean that it'll run 23th or..? And in that case, how can it be triggered the 24th if it's run the 23th?

Comment: `execution_date` can be used as macro. For example in SQL statements you can do: `WHERE date_column is between {{ execution_date }} and {{ next_execution_date }}` If your pipeline doesn't actually care about processing data between dates and all you are looking for is just executing something (for example copy a whole table to another database) then it doesn't really concern you.

Comment: All I want is the following: Today is the 24th/june 13:15. I deploy a DAG, and I want it to run each day at 1330. I set `schedule_interval = "30 13 * * *`, and if I understand you, I can set `start_date` as any time before 23th 1330 e.g `datetime(2021,23,6,13,0,0)` or does it have to be `datetime(2021,23,6,13,30)`?

Comment: I think I struggle to see how you calculate `start_date` +`schedule_interval` when `schedule_interval` is a crontab-syntax

Comment: your crontab actually just say once in 24 hours. Just do: `start_date=datetime(2021,23,6,13,30) schedule_interval = "30 13 * * *"` note that if you are running older Airflow version you might need to change the `dag_id`.