# How to get dags triggered automatically in airflow?

Tags: airflow

I have a dag scheduled for 7:42 pm on a daily basis, however, when i am manually triggering the dag it runs but not automatically.

 I am using official yaml file and running container, have set the timezone to IST by default, still no luck in automatically triggering dags

below is the code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.providers.ssh.operators.ssh import SSHOperator
from airflow.providers.sftp.operators.sftp import SFTPOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.ssh.hooks.ssh import SSHHook
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
              "owner": "airflow",
              "depends_on_past": False,
              "start_date": datetime(2021,6,24),
              "catchup":False,
              "email_on_failure": False,
              "email_on_retry": False,
              "retries": 1,
              "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5)
               }

dag = DAG("Email_report_final", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="42 19 * * *", template_searchpath  = ['/opt/airflow/scripts/'])
```

Comment: Are you sure that it should execute at least once behalf on scheduler? Because you have startdate 24.06 and if you dont have `backfill` flag it can not run already, because doesnt meet scheduled time, what is server time for now?

Comment: My server time is in IST, I thought that maybe giving start date for today (25/06/2021) is causing an issue that why I changed it.

Comment: @abhi if you change the start date for today, then the next run should be 26/06 at 7.42pm

Comment: @KaBoom I did change it to old date, but my dag is not getting automatically triggered.

Answer (score 2):

You setup your DAG with:

```
"start_date": datetime(2021,6,24)
schedule_interval="42 19 * * *"
```

This means the first scheduled run will start on `2021-06-25` at `19:42`. This is because Airflow schedule DAGs at the end of the interval.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68114523/14624409) to understand why Airflow behaves like that.

You can write [timezone aware DAGs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/timezone.html#time-zone-aware-dags) if you require to:

```
import pendulum

local_tz = pendulum.timezone("Asia/Calcutta") # India Standard Time

default_args=dict(
    start_date=datetime(2016, 1, 1, tzinfo=local_tz),
    owner='airflow'
)

dag = DAG('my_tz_dag', default_args=default_args)
op = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy', dag=dag)
print(dag.timezone) # <Timezone [Asia/Calcutta]>
```

Comment: `first scheduled run will start on 2021-06-25 at 19:42` Today is 28 however still my dag did  not run automatically.  
Am i missing something?