# Airflow scheduling for specific times each day

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have the following DAG set up:

```
default_dag_args = {
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 25, 0, 0),
    'email': 'foobar@foobar.com',
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
}

with models.DAG(
        'foobar',
        schedule_interval = "30 5,7,9 * * *",
        default_args=default_dag_args,
        catchup=False) as dag:
```

The behaviour that I want to have is that the DAG will execute at 5:30, 7:30 and 9:30 UTC every day. The behaviour that I'm seeing is that the 5:30 run executes at 7:30 UTC, the 7:30 run executes at 9:30 and the 9:30 run executes at 5:30 the next day.

I think I kind of have a vague idea of why this is happening based on the docs - 9:30 marks the end of the schedule period and so the 9:30 run executes at the beginning of the next period. I can't figure out how to get the behaviour I want though. The DAG doesn't have any reference to the schedule time in the code, it just needs to run at 5:30, 7:30 and 9:30 and the 'run time' as Airflow considers it doesn't matter.

Is there any way to get a DAG to run at absolute times? If not, what schedule can I set to get the behaviour I desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow is not a cron job scheduler. Airflow calculates `start_date + schedule_interval` and execute the job at the end of the interval. The reason behind this is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68114523/14624409).

In your case:
`start_date=datetime(2021,06,25)` with `schedule_interval = "30 5,7,9 * * *"` gives:

**1st** tasks with execution_date `2021-06-25 5:30` will start running on `2021-06-25 7:30`

**2nd** task with execution_date `2021-06-25 7:30` will start running on `2021-06-25 9:30`

**3rd** task with execution_date `2021-06-25 9:30` will start running on `2021-06-26 5:30`

**4th** task with execution_date `2021-06-26 5:30` will start running on `2021-06-26 7:30`

**5th** task with execution_date `2021-06-26 7:30` will start running on `2021-06-26 9:30`

**6th** task with execution_date `2021-06-26 9:30` will start running on `2021-06-27 5:30`

**7th** task with execution_date `2021-06-27 5:30` will start running on `2021-06-27 7:30`

**8th** task with execution_date `2021-06-27 7:30` will start running on `2021-06-27 9:30`

**9th** task with execution_date `2021-06-27 9:30` will start running on `2021-06-28 5:30`

and so on...

Note that you still get 3 runs per day (except the first date) as you expect it just a matter of understanding how scheduling works. If you want to get 3 runs on the first date as well then change your `start_date` to `datetime(2021,06,24,9,30)`. The execution_date is a logical date. If needed you can reference relevant dates within your DAG code usings [macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html) - for example:

I mentioned that the **6th** run `execution_date` is `2021-06-26 9:30` using macros with that runs can give you:

`prev_execution_date` is `2021-06-26 7:30`

`next_execution_date` is `2021-06-27 5:30`

Note: your code has `catchup=False` so the exact dates I wrote here won't be the same but that effects only on the first run. The following runs will follow the same logic.